# How to get @@identity in Visual Studio 2012 using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, identity

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand
    Dim rd, rd1, rd2 As SqlDataReader
    Dim lastid As String

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ELMAR-PC\ELMAR;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True;"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd1.Connection = con
    cmd2.Connection = con
    cmd3.Connection = con
    con.Open()

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or RadioButton3.Checked = False And RadioButton4.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all the required fields", vbCritical)
    End If


    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblquestion (question,type)values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "') "
    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY "
    ' TextBox11.Text = Val(cmd1.CommandText)
    lastid = cmd1.CommandText
    cmd2.CommandText = "update tblquestion set question_id ='" + lastid + "' where ID='" + lastid + "'limit 1"
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    con.Close()
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
' Validation
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or RadioButton3.Checked = False And RadioButton4.Checked = False Then
    MsgBox("Please fill all the required fields", vbCritical)
    Exit Sub
End If

' Open connection
Dim con As New SqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ELMAR-PC\ELMAR;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True;"
con.Open()

Dim lastid As Int32

'Execute first insert
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblquestion (question,type)values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

lastid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) 'this will give you the identity
cmd.Dispose()

'Execute second insert with lastid
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
cmd1.Connection = con
cmd1.CommandText = "update tblquestion set question_id ='" + lastid + "' where ID='" + lastid + "'limit 1"
rd = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd1.Dispose()

'Close connection
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both `INSERT` and `SELECT @@IDENTITY` into a single command text. And then use [executeScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the value.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblquestion (question,type) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "'); "
cmd.CommandText &= "SELECT @@IDENTITY "
lastid = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 'this will give you the identity
```

Side note: Instead of using string concatenation above to construct your query, use [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1) - it will save you a lot of pain, including [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**EDIT:** I still recommend getting the identity at the time of insertion. But if you need to retrieve it elsewhere in code at another time, you can use

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblquestion"
```

Comment: i tried using the codes you gave, the result is that it makes a duplicate entry in the database, what i need is to get the value of the last inputted identity, and use it to fill another collum

Comment: Then don't do the insert. I assumed that you need to do the insert and get the identity back right away. In your case you can simple do something like  `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblquestion`. But why're are u having both `ID` and `question_id` with the same value?

Comment: because we have another table that we have to use the value of the identity for several entries :)

Comment: thanks for the answers but i still haven't gotten the right result.

Comment: i need to pass the value of the last identity to another column, which is question_id...

Comment: Don't bother doing `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblquestion`... Imagine someone doing multiple inserts on the first table, how will you diferentiate the records? When executing an insert, you should always to retrieve the @@identity value on the same statement (like @Yuriy Galanter first example shows)...

Comment: how will we be able to retrieve the value of the last ID, and then input it in the same row but in the question_id column :)